# Jest/expect "toEquals" failing with undefined properties

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm using `expect(item).toEqual(otherItem)`. Acording to everything I've read, `expect({ a: "a", b: undefined }).toEqual({ a: "a" })` should pass. Otherwise I should be using `toStrictEqual`. [E.g. here, in "basic matches"](https://github.com/sapegin/jest-cheat-sheet/blob/master/Readme.md).

However, I'm getting a failure with the output:

```
     Array [
       Object {
   +     "alertId": undefined,
         "attributes": Array [],
         "destination": "_b",
         "kind": "kind",
         "linkable": "Unlinkable",
         "source": "_a",
   +     "validFrom": undefined,
   +     "validTo": undefined,
       },
   -   Object {
   -     "attributes": Array [],
   -     "destination": "_c",
   -     "kind": "kind",
   -     "linkable": "Unlinkable",
   -     "source": "_a",
   -   },
     ]
```

Any idea why?

Comment: If the expected object doesn't have the same properties as the object, the test will fail even if the value is undefined. Solution would be to fix your function to remove undefined values or expect the property with undefined value to be in the object.

Comment: How come `expect([{ a: "a", b: undefined }]).toEqual([{ a: "a" }]);` passes then? I'm also testing this function in about 10 tests, it passes every single one despite them all having `undefined` values. In fact, even in this same `expect` it passes on *one* of the values, and fails the other. They both have `undefined`!

Comment: Ah! I'm being an idiot. The problem isn't actually the `undefined`, the whole object is missing. Jest is working as expected.

Comment: Well, I learned something new as well. Didn't know `toEqual` will loosely match the object.

Comment: Yeah, they added `toStrictEqual` for strict checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah. I'm an idiot. There's nothing wrong with jest, the test is correctly failing. I'm reading the output of Jest wrong.

It's saying the whole object:

```
-   Object {
-     "attributes": Array [],
-     "destination": "_c",
-     "kind": "kind",
-     "linkable": "Unlinkable",
-     "source": "_a",
```

Is missing from the array. Although it is also reporting the `undefined` as a difference, it's not the thing causing `toEqual` to fail. Notice the `destination` is different. The test should be returning two objects.